# SFMC emails sent by bounce.mycompanydomain.com

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-domain, bounce-management

Is it normal that the emails from Marketing Cloud are sent by a domain like : bounce.mycompanydomain.com ?

The "bounce" is quite confusing.

Is there something specific about bounce domain ?

Comment: Sounds like you're sending from a subdomain.  When sending out of an ESP, you provision a Sender Authentication Package in which you provide a sending domain which is more typically a subdomain.

Comment: As integrator, it seems that all the SFMC platforms on which we work send emails with a "mailed-by : bounce.companysenderdomain" (it is not the "From", but the "Mailed-by" that we can see on the "To me" details in an email received in Gmail). I was just wondering if it was "normal" or if it is a specific configuration.

Comment: Because the Sender Authentication Domain configured on their org is the "companysenderdomain" part.

Answer (score 1):

In this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000316875&type=1) you can find an explanation -

> Subscribers may see 'Via' because the 'From Address' being used in a Sender Profile is not using an authenticated domain (SAP or Private Domain). The 'Mailed-By' will always display the bounce host assigned to your account.

Comment: Where is your link meant to go? It just links back to this question :/

Comment: Hey @J.M.Janzen, fixed the link.